# safe Iterator.max

Tags: scala, iterator

Is there a library that offers a function like `Iterator.max`, but that returns an `Option[A]` rather than an `A` to account for possibly-empty iterators? Alternately, is there a library that offers a class `PosInf[A]` or so that adjoins a positive infinity to `A`?

(Obviously either of these is mere gruntwork to do myself, but using a library is almost always preferable to duplicating code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/)**: `MA.maximum`. Usage:

```
import scalaz._; import Scalaz._

List(1, 2, 3).maximum == Some(3)

List.empty[Int].maximum == None
```

the only problem is that this does not work with Iterators directly, so you would have to use a `Stream` instead (e.g. using `Iterator.toStream`)

```
List(1, 2, 3).iterator.toStream.maximum = Some(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of anything but this is simple:

```
def maxOpt[T: Numeric](i: Iterator[T]) = if (i.hasNext) Some(i.max) else None
```

Edit: Numeric is too strong a requirement, Ordering is enough:

```
def maxOpt[T: Ordering](i: Iterator[T]) = if (i.hasNext) Some(i.max) else None
```

And if you use `isEmpty` is should work on any subclass of `TraversableOnce`